# Convert C# code to IL code

Tags: c#, .net, il

How I can get IL code of C# code ? Can I do this with a extern library, or exists internal functions ? 
**EDIT :** I want to show IL code in my application with a MessageBox.

Comment: @dlev: Not quite.  I think the OP wants it in human-readable form.

Comment: @Robert: Perhaps, though the question is sufficiently vague that I felt a (somewhat) snarky comment was warranted. Honestly, without more context, I'm not 100% sure what is being asked (i.e. do they want to see IL in human-readable form from compiled code, do they want to pass in some code to a function which returns an array of IL instructions...)

Comment: I want to show in a dialogBox the IL code, so I can't use ildasm.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Programmatically? You can use reflection to get a `MethodInfo`, and then call [`MethodBase.GetMethodBody`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) to get the body. From the `MethodBody`, you can call [`GetILAsByteArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbody.getilasbytearray.aspx) amongst other things.

Of course, if you just want to examine it yourself, there's [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/), [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/), ildasm (part of the .NET SDK) and no doubt other tools...

Comment: What would you do with that?  Build your own compiler?

Comment: I want a c# method, so your first sentence seems the good answer. Thanks Jon!

Comment: @malinois: I assume you're after *already compiled* C# code as IL, by the way? `CSharpCodeProvider` will allow you to compile C# *source* code into IL.

Comment: @Jon, I see. I still think "Jon Skeet" is a team of developers, even though you were on thisDevelopersLife. You are the face of the group. ;)

Comment: @Jethro: If someone were picking a face for a group of developers, I'd hope they could come up with a better one than mine :)

Comment: @Jon, hahaha, we shall battle on these dev grounds again someday. IE (Getting late in RSA and I need some sleep.) :)

Comment: @Jon, I use CSharpCodeProvider to create dlls with .cs file, but not to get IL code. It's possible to do that ? I wnat to make a functionnality like .net reflector, to show IL code of a dll using reflexion.

Comment: @Jon, Have you an answer for this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570457

Answer (score 6):

Use IL Disassembler like this:

```
c:\il>csc Class.cs    
c:\il>ildasm /output=Class.il Class.exe
```

you'll both have the IL & the exe.

Answer (score 6):

Just open a Visual Studio command prompt and type **ildasm** - with ildasm you can open up any assembly and show the generated IL.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at LinqPad, it has options to see IL.

Answer (score 1):

OR,

```
Start -> Programs -> Microsoft .NET Framework SDK (Version) -> Tools -> MSIL Disassembler
```

Answer (score 1):

It's quite an old question, but I'd like to add some accuracies.

`GetMethodBody()` will give you at best a byte array, which you need to parse manually (which can be painful since some opcodes have two bytes) to get a human readable text.

I just want to mention [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) as an alternate solution.

It's open source, meaning you can debug it and integrate with it in your solution.